# Is there a way to trace which IP that access my printer?

Tags: networking, printer

I have one shared printer Epson TMU220 via LAN to print a bill. And sometimes it printed some random character from guest. I want to find which computer use my printer.

This is my printer:

[image]

Is there a way to find which IP address that access my printer?

most of my computer use win xp.

Comment: What's your printer? It'd be stored on your printer, not your computer.

Comment: @Chipperyman see edit

Comment: What model is it? A picture does very little and I'm unable to figure it out based on the URL because it's on imgur.

Comment: I just utilized my amazing google-search-by-image-fu, is it the Epson u220? I want to confirm before I try to research this.

Comment: yes it is TMU220 , I already include the model in my question

Answer (score 1):

You can use a protocol analyser such as WireShark https://www.wireshark.org/ to see what packets are on your network, and where they are coming from.  You might be able to use that to identify your "guest" - but it will require some deep knowledge of networking terminology.

Good luck!

Comment: I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add a bridge between the printer and the network and then sniff the traffic on the bridge (eg Using Wireshark).  The thing is that just using Wireshark on a typical LAN won't work unless you run it on each device, as the other devices on the network won't see the traffic.  (You might be able to substitute an old hub and use that for testing - hubs broadcast the traffic to all devices, of-course, hubs are ancient, slow technology).

Comment: So are those printers so it'd be fine.